# ffmpeg & error handling

Tags: python, exception, ffmpeg

i am using ffmpeg to resize image with this command :
`ffmpeg -i 0%d.jpg -qmax 1 -vf scale=-1:480 out-0%d.jpg` , and sometimes he return me error :

Assertion s->nb_components == 3 failed at /home/kyle/software/ffmpeg/source/ffmp
eg-git/libavcodec/mjpegdec.c:354

And i see the box ffmpeg.exe has stop working ... and i need to hit cancel for continue my python script loop.

1) It there something wrong with the original size of the jpg ?

2) If there is no solution how can i ignore the runtime error message and let my python script continu where it was.

Thank you :)

Comment: i use os.system("ffmpeg -i 0%d.jpg -qmax 1 -vf scale=-1:480 out-0%d.jpg") for my python script command

Comment: Why `ffmpeg`? ImageMagick is usually more than enough to do this (`convert`).

Comment: seem to be hard working from imagemagick & windows command prompt !? how will u do a batch image convertor ?

Comment: lol ... i think imagemagick update or change my ffmpeg version and now the ffmpeg command is not making me a runtime error ... ! weird